# Read and get item value of a remote json

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json.net

how can I output the items "total_sales" or totals.orders from a remote json like http://www.example.com/api/stats.json in asp.net (4.5) with vb?

```
{
  "sales": {
    "total_sales": "556.20",
    "net_sales": "402.35",
    "average_sales": "402.35",
    "total_orders": 12,
    "total_items": 24,
    "total_tax": "88.81",
    "total_shipping": "65.04",
    "total_refunds": 0,
    "total_discount": "0.00",
    "totals_grouped_by": "day",
    "totals": {
      "2017-03-17": {
        "sales": "556.20",
        "orders": 12,
        "items": 24,
        "tax": "88.80",
        "shipping": "65.04",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      }
    },
    "total_customers": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) then:

```
Dim sales as JObject = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString)
Dim totSales as String = Cstr(sales.GetValue("total_sales"))
```

Comment: Is "yourJsonString" the url? Think there must be a stream technique.

Comment: yourJsonString contains json, find how to download it from url

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  Using your JSON string, I retrieve total sales.

First add references:

```
Imports System.Web.HttpContext
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
```

Next Get the remote JSON, I'll assume that the response is the string you provide.  We use HttpWebRequest to get remote JSON.

```
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("www.SomeURL.com/?Parameter=somevalue")
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()

    Dim enc As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
    Dim loResponseStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc)
    Dim Response As String = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd()
    Dim jss As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim dict As Object = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(Response)
    Dim KeyValue As String = (dict("sales")("total_sales"))
    loResponseStream.Close()
```

R/
Prescott ...